# What is the proper SQL syntax for TOP WITH TIES in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle does not allow TOP WITH TIES so I was wondering how can I write this not using TOP WITH TIES to comply with Oracle DB standards? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Oracle v12.1+ has its own row limiting function:

```
SELECT
    S.EmpID,
    S.Ename,
    ...
FROM
    SalesPersons S
LEFT JOIN ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me the name of the command. I just have one question, why is my output negative? In Microsoft SQL it was positive (it retrieved the same person though, just with a negative salary now)